# Applying styling ONLY to specific class within another class in Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, style, stylesheets

Is there a way to apply a CSS rule to a specific class only if it is within another?

For instance, if I wanted to make the background black for a class `black` within the class `container` but not set the background for all my `black` classes, the equivalent with a normal HTML/CSS file would be:

```
.container .black{
    background: #000000; 
}
```

I haven't come across any syntax that replicates with behavior with Aura components. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the exact same thing in Aura, except you prefix the CSS selector with .THIS (which will be populated with a unique CSS identifier when rendered).

```
.THIS .container .black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

If container happens to be a top-level element, do not include the first space:

```
.THIS.container .black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: I've found this works when styling a class within an element, ex) .THIS div .black {} but it doesn't work for a class within a class, ex) .THIS .class1 .black{}

Comment: @Khan It definitely does work. I even wrote a small app in my Dev Org to make sure it does. There is probably a simple mistake in your code somewhere.

Comment: Fair enough! I'll go back and check everything. Thanks!